# JavaScript does not work when it is in an html-file which is included in another html-file with “w3-include-html”

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script (JavaScript) in the HTML file "2020-X".
"2020-X" is included in the HTML file "index-X" using a w3-include-html attribute.

My problem is that the script in "2020-X" does not work when the file "2020-X" is included in "index-X".
When the file "2020-X" runs directly, the script works.
What's wrong and how can I fix it?

This is from file "index-X":

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.lovest.no/MinScript.js"></script> <!-- Function includeHTML -->
</head>

<body> 
    <p>This is from file "index-X".</p>
    <div w3-include-html="https://www.lovest.no/6-Blogger/2020-X.html"></div>   
    <script> includeHTML();</script>
</body>
```

This is from file "2020-X":

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="demo">Script in file "2020-X": 
    <br>Does NOT work when "2020-X" is included in "index-X". 
    <br>Works only when "2020-X" is startet alone/direct. 
    <br>What is wrong?
    </p>

    <script> 
    <!-- $(document).ready(function(){  (Have tried this too) -->       
        function myFunction(a, b) {
            return a * b;
        }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Script in file '2020-X': It works! And the answer is: " + myFunction(15, 2); 
    <!-- }); -->        
    </script>
</body>
```

[Run index-X](https://www.lovest.no/index-X.html)
[Run 2020-X alone](https://www.lovest.no/6-Blogger/2020-X.html)

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with [W3C](https://www.w3.org/) Are you talking about [W3.js](https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/default.asp)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I meant W3.js. I was wrong. Has now removed the tag.

Comment: W3.js uses innerHTML. See the duplicate.  It's a really low quality library in general (and W3Schools is really low quality in general).

Comment: you can make a java script file and include it in both HTML files